# NASM shift operators

Tags: assembly, x86, bit-manipulation, nasm

How would you go about doing a bit shift in NASM on a register? I read the manual and it only seems to mention these operators **>>**, **<<**. When I try to use them NASM complains about the shift operator working on scalar values. Can you explain what a scalar value is and give an example of how to use **>>** and **<<**. Also, I thought there were a **shr** or **shl** operators. If they do exist can you give an example of how to use them? Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`<<` and `>>` are for use with integer constants only. This is what it means by "scalar value". You can shift the value in a register using the `shl` or `shr` instructions. They are used to shift the value in a register left or right, respectively, a given number of bits.

The first line in this example shifts the value in `ax` left 4 bits, which is the same as multiplying it by 16. The second line shifts the value in `bx` right by 2 bits, which is the same as integer division by 4.

```
shl ax, 4
shr bx, 2
```

You can also use `cl` to indicate the number of bits to shift, instead of a constant. For more information on these and related instructions, see [this page](https://web.archive.org/web/20120426171627/https://www.arl.wustl.edu/~lockwood/class/cs306/books/artofasm/Chapter_6/CH06-3.html).

Answer (score 6):

Piggy-backing on ughoavgfhw's answer... to use `<<` and `>>`, use them directly on constants:

```
MOV EAX, 1 << 2    ; Puts 4 into EAX
MOV EAX, 2 << 2    ; Puts 8 into EAX
MOV EAX, 8 >> 1    ; Puts 4 into EAX
```