# Explain This Instruction Set And Z-Register

Tags: assembly, avr

I'm not understanding the following code very well. Specifically, what does the two lines with the question marks do? What does `seg_table<<1` do?

In general, what is the purpose of the z-register?

```
nc1_m:
    lpm r21, z
    ldi zh, high(seg_table<<1) <--?
    ldi zl, low(seg_table<<1)  <--?
    add zl, r20
    brcc nc2_m
    inc zh

seg_table:      
    .dw 0xeb09              ; 1, 0
    .dw 0xc185              ; 3, 2
    .dw 0x5163              ; 5, 4
    .dw 0xcb11              ; 7, 6
    .dw 0x4101              ; 9, 8 
    .dw 0x00ff              ; on, off
```

If it helps, the microprocessor I'm using is the [ATtiny48](http://www.atmel.com/Images/doc8008.pdf)

Comment: you can start with looking at the shift operator http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9960476/nasm-shift-operators

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [document you linked](http://www.atmel.com/Images/doc8008.pdf) describes the purpose of the Z register:

> Six of the 32 registers can be used as three 16-bit indirect address register > pointers for Data
> Space addressing – enabling efficient address calculations. One of the these
> address pointers
> can also be used as an address pointer for look up tables in Flash program
> memory. These
> added function registers are the 16-bit X-, Y-, and Z-register, described
> later in this section.

> #### The X-register, Y-register, and Z-register
>
> The registers R26:R31 have some added functions to their general purpose usage.
> These registers
> are 16-bit address pointers for indirect addressing of the data space. [...]
>
> In the different addressing modes these address registers have functions as fixed displacement,
> automatic increment, and automatic decrement (see the instruction set reference for details).

The intent of the the code example is to load the Z register with the address of a byte at offset R20 in `seg_table`. Your example example is incomplete, following the example code would be an LPM instruction that fetched the byte from program memory.

The address of `segtable` needs to be shifted over to the left (the equivalent of multiplying by two) because the assembler/linker treats the program memory as being word (16-bit) addressable, while the LPM instruction addresses program memory by bytes. In other words to the assembler the address of `segtable` is an offset measured in 16-bit words from the start of program memory. To the LPM instruction the value contained in the Z register is interpreted as an offset measured in 8-bit bytes from the start of program memory. To convert the address of `segtable` to an offset usable with LPM it needs to multiplied by two.

If it's not clear, values in the `segtable` are bit masks for a 7 segment LED display.